# Paypal Buttons Are Not Showing on Angular Production in Dynamics CRM Marketing Event Website

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, dynamics-crm, dynamics-marketing

I've used Paypal Javascript-Sdk in Dynamics CRM Marketing Module Event Website Which is By Default on Angular So It is Working Fine on LocalHost

But When I Tried to Deploy This on Powerappsportals then Somehow it is not Loading & Giving The Following Error on Developer's Console

```
main.js:2 ERROR ReferenceError: paypal is not defined
    at e.payment (main.js:2)
    at e.ngAfterViewInit (main.js:2)
    at fo (main.js:2)
    at ho (main.js:2)
    at po (main.js:2)
    at ai (main.js:2)
    at vi (main.js:2)
    at mi (main.js:2)
    at ai (main.js:2)
    at vi (main.js:2)
```

So I Realized That Somehow That Paypal SDK is Failed to Load on Production

If Someone Has Already Resolved That Issue Please Help Me On This

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally I Found a Solution By Myself.

In **Dynamics Portal Management Web Template** Section There is a **Index.html** File Defined. Somehow They Restricted Us to Use The Same Format. So, When I Tried To Deploy My Angular Application. Dynamics Was Expecting The Index File With The Same Format. So It Neglected The Additional Scripts in Header Section.

So, I Just Added The Paypal Script in That File in Header Section & Now Problem Is Resolved. It is Now Showing Button on Production As Well.